# What's the Java equivalent to C++'s for_each template?

Tags: java, c++

In the following code you're able to apply any Function f (e.g., add, subtract, etc.). How do I do that through Java?

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
  Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f)
  {
    for ( ; first!=last; ++first ) f(*first);
    return f;
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a Java book? C++ is not Java, you shouldn't try to learn Java *through* C++, you should learn it from the ground up. (Nothing states there is necessarily an equivalence; even if there were, that might not be the best way in Java.)

Comment: @GMan: yeah sure, I'm just trying to apply the concept that's all, if I can't apply it. I'll just make multiple functions. It's just that I know something in C++ and I would like to make use of it in java if available

Comment: In that case you probably want generics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two major changes you'll need to make to this code to make it work in Java.  First, you'll need to replace the STL-style iterators with Java-style iterators, which fortunately isn't too hard.  Second, you'll have to change the use of a function pointer or functor parameter with an object of a different type, since Java does not support function pointers.

In Java, iterators are heavier than in C++ and encapsulate the full range they traverse, not just the start or end of that range.  With a Java iterator, you use the .next() and .hasNext() methods to walk across the range.

As for the function parameter, you will probably need to create your own interface representing some object that can be called as a function.  For example:

```
public interface Operation<T> {
    void apply(T argument);
}
```

This interface is a generic parameterized on some type T saying what the argument type is, and then exports a function called apply() that applies the function.

Given this, a simple but naive way to replicate for_each would be to write

```
public static <T> forEach(Iterator<T> itr, Operation<T> op) {
    while (itr.hasNext())
        op.apply(itr.next());
}
```

The reason I say that this is naive is that it doesn't use bounded wildcards correctly to expand the scope of where it can be used.  A more proper version that's more Java-friendly would be this:

```
public static <T> forEach(Iterator<T> itr, Operation<? super T> op) {
    while (itr.hasNext())
        op.apply(itr.next());
}
```

Consult a reference on Java genetics for why this works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: (Wouldn't the posh for loop be better: `for (T obj : itr) { op.apply(obj); }`. Edit: Oh, you've used `Iterator`. Use `Iterable`!

Comment: Can you use that type of loop on iterators directly?  I thought that only worked on arrays and Iterables.

Comment: Er, yes. But then the use of `Iterable` would be closer to the use of iterators in C++, and idiomatic for Java.

Answer (score 0):

To implement the template class you'd use [Java Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

For the callback, more than likely you'd want to create an [Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) and pass an object that implemented it to the Generic class where you'd call the method defined therin.

Answer (score 0):

You should use interfaces, but if you want to do it in the hard way, using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) (not tested, not exception-checked, etc. But you can get the idea):

```
public void myFunction(Collection items, String methodName) {
    foreach(Object o : items) {
        Method method = o.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
        method.invoke(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With good OO design, first through last would be objects of a specific (implements an interface) type and f() would take an object of that type (interface) as a parameter so you are done--it's pretty much like you wrote.

if you are talking about doing it on primitives instead then it's going to need generics, but at this point you'd want to look for a better design or better way to do that.

You didn't really give enough info for a more detailed answer, if we knew more about the problem you were trying to solve and the restrictions we might be able to give better advice.